# Vscode Snippet to Remove Leading Whitespace of Non-Empty Lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here are two snippets

```
"Remove leading whitespace": {
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(\\s+)//gm}"
    ],
    "description": "Remove leading whitespace"
},

"Replace non-empty lines with 'xyz'": {
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^.+$/xyz/gm}"
    ],
    "description": "Replace non-empty lines with 'xyz'"
}
```

The first one remove leading whitespaces (but also remove the emoty lines) the other replace non-empty lines with 'xyz'.

I want the snippet to remove leading whitespace of non-empty lines (preserving non-empty line as shown in Replace non-empty lines with 'xyz'). So I want to transform following text

```
Working towards

    long-term goals or aspirations



can provide motivation


        challenges and obstacles
```

to

```
Working towards

long-term goals or aspirations



can provide motivation


challenges and obstacles
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a positive look ahead

```
"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([ \\t]+)(?=\\S)//gm}"
```

Comment: `"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(\\s+)(?=\\S)//gm}"` also remove the empty lines. I want to keep the blank lines as it is.

Comment: If the OP would be okay with removing spaces/tabs from otherwise empty lines then `^([ \\t]+)` is sufficient.